# Multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, zip

What i have:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5]]


b = [["hallo"]],[["bye"]]
```

What I want:

```
new1 = [[1,2,3,4,5],"hallo"]
new2 = [[2,3,4,5],"bye"]
```

the hardest part is that i want it in a way that when the user puts a extra list in a and b, it will not error but automatic add the new inputs to a new list (e.g. new 3 [with a [third], [b "third"]]

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: If a tuple is what you actually want, just use the zip () function directly. It returns back a list of tuples.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you could use `zip` function:

```
In [31]: new1, new2 = map(list, zip(a, b))

In [32]: new1
Out[32]: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [['hallo']]]

In [33]: new2
Out[33]: [[2, 3, 4, 5], [['bye']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and unpacking:

```
>>> new1, new2 = list(zip(a, [x[0][0] for x in b]))
>>> new1
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'hallo')
>>> new2
([2, 3, 4, 5], 'bye')
```

Obviously extra lists require that you adapt your code to `n` items and not assume two, but the trick is the same.

Comment: Ty, but this prints: new1 as: ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'h') instead of ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'hallo")